# Grabbing information in div on click

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble finding the answer to this problem. I've searched around for 2 hours now and have only gotten to dead ends.

```
<table>
    <tr class="masterclass">
        <td class="subClass1"><img src="#" alt="Text Here 1" /></td>
        <td class="subClass2"><p>Random Information Here</p></td>
        <td class="subClass3"><a href="linkhere" class="buttonStyle">Submit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="masterclass">
        <td class="subClass1"><img src="#" alt="Text Here 2" /></td>
        <td class="subClass2"><p>Random Information Here</p></td>
        <td class="subClass3"><a href="linkhere" class="buttonStyle">Submit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="masterclass">
        <td class="subClass1"><img src="#" alt="Text Here 3" /></td>
        <td class="subClass2"><p>Random Information Here</p></td>
        <td class="subClass3"><a href="linkhere" class="buttonStyle">Submit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="masterclass">
        <td class="subClass1"><img src="#" alt="Text Here 4" /></td>
        <td class="subClass2"><p>Random Information Here</p></td>
        <td class="subClass3"><a href="linkhere" class="buttonStyle">Submit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

All I would like to do is when the link is clicked, I would like to alert what the alt tag text is for the image only for that table row.

This is the code I currently have:

```
$('a.buttonStyle').click(function() {
    var thing = $('subClass1').siblings().attr('alt');
    alert(thing);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('a.buttonStyle').click(function() {
    var thing = $(this).closest('.masterclass').find('.subClass1 img').attr('alt');
    alert(thing);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5JAF2/)**

By the way, you didn't close your image tags properly.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know there was such a thing as ".closest" I have one problem though, I didn't realize... in <td class="subClass1"></td> There is a <span> and the image is actually in that span.... do I have to change the code?

Comment: Not necessary. If the code doesn't work you can try `.find('.subClass1 span img')`, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that currently your HTML markup is invalid, you need to close the `alt` attribute value as well as closing the `img` tag.

After correct it then you can use:

```
$('a.buttonStyle').click(function() {
    var thing = $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.subClass1').find('img').attr('alt');
    alert(thing);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJLxE/)**

or even shorter but less strict:

```
$('a.buttonStyle').click(function() {
    var thing = $(this).parent().siblings('.subClass1').children().attr('alt');
    alert(thing);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJLxE/1/)**